# Parse Import Table Image Issue

Tags: parse-platform

I am working on exporting a table from one parse account to another. Importing the table was successful. When I tried opening image from parse dashboard (One Which imported the table) it says access denied (Screenshot Attached).
[image: Error on clicking on image in a table]

Comment: The `PFObject` for files contains pointer to a `URL` which leads to the file i.e. image in this case. When you try to access it from another database, it obviously throws access restriction exception. Only your original parse app is authorized to view those files. At least that's what I remember. Please read Documentation on files.

Answer (score 0):

On importing, Parse will change the unique id of the `File` url to your new app, this is why the images are not working. Unfortunately, there is no way to solve this at the moment.

The Parse team is working on a clone feature that moves all your records along with the file data. This is still under development.